# Android. Get listview item onClick inner button to new child fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment with a ListView of `row` items. A `row` consist in just am `ImageView`

fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <!-- Rightend Play Button. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a `ResourceCursorAdapter` to fill this `ListView`. I just assign to each ImageView a click listener. It plays a record saved in the provided path.

```
private abstract class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAadpter {

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        // Play button.
        ImageView playButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String record = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.RECORD));
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Play record in path [record]. Not the problem.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to open a new fragment `Fragment_2` in a `row` click. This fragment has the same play_button, and has to play the same record.

fragment_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_audio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment2">

    <!-- Play Button. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How can I manage that this button plays the same record than in `Fragment_1`?** I think I could be able if I have a hidden TextView with the path of the record, but sure you have a smarter solution.

In my `onCreateView` of `Fragment_1`.

```
mList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
// Click event for single row.
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // TODO: Go to fragment_2 and has the same view [view.findViewById(R.id.play_button)]
    }
});
```

Comment: i would recommend you to edit your problem, and clearly state your problem. Also post code instead of image.

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati Sorry I had problems when uploading code, but it's all correct now :) Is there anything unclear about the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Communication between fragments should be done through the associated Activity. You can use interface for this. it Will serve as contract and bridge between them.

Let's have the following components:

> **An activity** hosts fragments and allow fragments communication
>
> **FragmentA** first fragment which will send data
>
> **FragmentB** second fragment which will receive datas from **FragmentA**

FragmentA's implementation is:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
  DataPassListener mCallback;
  public interface DataPassListener{
    public void passData(String data);
  }
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Make sure that container activity implement the callback interface
    try {
      mCallback = (DataPassListener)activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement DataPassListener");
    }
  }
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Suppose that when a button clicked second FragmentB will be inflated
    // some data on FragmentA will pass FragmentB
    // Button passDataButton = (Button).........
    passDataButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.passDataButton) {
          mCallback.passData("Text to pass FragmentB");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

MainActivity implementation is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DataPassListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new FragmentA()).commit();
    }
}
@Override
public void passData(String data) {
    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(FragmentB.DATA_RECEIVE, data);
    fragmentB .setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragmentB )
        .commit();
}
}
```

FragmentB implementation is:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
final static String DATA_RECEIVE = "data_receive";
TextView showReceivedData;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_B, container, false);
    showReceivedData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showReceivedData);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        showReceivedData.setText(args.getString(DATA_RECEIVE));
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
This document has given information in detail, you can go through it.

In your situation, you can apply this way to communicate between two fragments.

Comment: And in my case, how do I extract `Text to pass FragmentB`. I want to pass it the path where my record is, but I just have the onClick to play this record. How can I save the path String for each row listview. In my question, this String would be `record`.

Comment: as you can see in the example, you can pass the value using bundle, and extract it where you need.

Comment: In the example, i have passed Text from FragmentA to FragmentB.

Comment: But my problem is that I don't know where to save this String for each ListView row. Maybe in a list accesed by the row position? Or I can also have a hidden TextView for each row view.

Comment: yes, You can pass position id (assuming you have string attached in rows - this may/can come from API/Internet/local storage to your listView) to track it, and pass it to fragmentB.

Comment: After adapting code to my project, I have realized that `DATA_RECEIVE` is static. So, wouldn't it easier to do `FragmentB.DATA_RECEIVE = "Text to pass FragmentB"` ?

Comment: you can try! + i am assuming, you want string to be changed, so when clicking on Id position, you can get the string, and pass it with it, so you can set that string to DATA_RECEIVE. hope you got it